# getting understand jsonp json call back explanation

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp

this is the code:

```
  $.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: url,
            jsonCallback: 'jsonp',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

            }
          });
```

**in var url i put the link before that code piece.
i understood the data type jsonp because of the other domain, but i didnt understood
what is the meaning of calling the jsoncallback jsonp either?(jsonCallback: 'jsonp')

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Specify the callback function name for a JSONP request. This value will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by jQuery. It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling. You may want to specify the callback when you want to enable better browser caching of GET requests.

So, usually jQuery creates a function with a random name and sends that name in the URL, e.g.

```
callback=jQuery_12345678903836482648
```

But if you set that option with that value, jQuery will append

```
callback=jsonp
```